# TSQL Find MIN/MAX LEN ColName over many tables

Tags: sql-server, max, maxlength

I need to find the MAX LEN for all responses in column across many tables. Some of these column names match across tables, some don't. If they match, I need to use the column name through all the tables that it matches. So, say 10 tables with a total of 200 different column names. I created a TempCol table. I also have all the table names in a temp table. My thought is to add cols to the TempCol table for Table1MAX, Table1MIN, Table2MAX, Table2MIN etc.

This finds the MAX (IF Col_1 is in Table1):

```
SELECT MAX(LEN(Col_1)) FROM Table1
```

I'd like to fill in the TempCol table, with the values from above, but I keep hitting a wall.
Anybody have any ideas?

Comment: What is the purpose of doing such a thing? Can you please explain the scenario?

Comment: Looking to recreate a database where all columns were defined as varchar(MAX). Unrealistic to do same in new db as it will be growing almost exponentially. Don't want to lose data in the coversion, so I need the maxlength for each col name for each table.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way, for the MAX length only; you can use it as a starting point and modify/extend it to include more information in the results table:

```
create table dbo.Results (
    TableName sysname not null,
    ColumnName sysname not null,
    MaxLength int not null default 0,
    primary key (TableName, ColumnName)
)

insert into dbo.Results (TableName, ColumnName)
select object_name(sc.object_id), sc.name
from sys.columns sc
join sys.types st
on sc.system_type_id = st.system_type_id
-- get data for varchar(max) columns only
where st.name = 'varchar' and sc.max_length = -1 

declare @TableName sysname, @ColumnName sysname, @sql nvarchar(max)

declare TablesAndColumns cursor local fast_forward
for
select TableName, ColumnName
from dbo.Results

open TablesAndColumns
fetch next from TablesAndColumns into @TableName, @ColumnName
while @@fetch_status = 0
begin
    set @sql =  'update dbo.Results set MaxLength = (select isnull(max(len(' + @ColumnName + ')),0) ' +
                ' from ' + @TableName + ') ' +
                ' where TableName = ''' + @TableName + ''' and ColumnName = ''' + @ColumnName + ''''
    print @sql      
    exec sp_executesql @sql

    fetch next from TablesAndColumns into @TableName, @ColumnName
end

close TablesAndColumns
deallocate TablesAndColumns

select * from dbo.Results
```

Using cursors and dynamic SQL isn't always a good idea, but for a one-time system task like this it's a reasonable approach.

Comment: I gave it a go and ended up with no rows in the table. A problem may be the Data Types? They vary: int, bit, numeric, varchar, nvarchar and worst of all 'ntext'. I built another temp table with all the Table names, the column names,the data types and a "MaxLen" column. I can't even get that to update:I've tried

Comment: sorry ...I've tried: UPDATE p
SET p.MAX_LEN =  MAX(LEN(CAST(FieldName AS nvarchar(MAX))))            
  FROM TempFieldNamesTable  p

Comment: I'm not so good at this ... but I get an aggregate error. I'm about to do it by hand, but there are actually > 20 tables and > 700 field names.

Comment: As I commented in the code, this example only looks at `varchar(max)` columns, so if you have other requirements then you need to modify the script. Have you read and understood the code? Did you examine the SQL statements displayed by the `PRINT` statements? And data types like `int` or `numeric` [have fixed storage sizes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187745.aspx) anyway.

Comment: Sorry - I am just not that advanced. I tried commenting out the  WHERE clause, but that didn't help.